# bot.say не робит а в оссобенности иммено sat

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot


bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('online')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def hello(ctx):
    await bot.say ("hello, world")

bot.run("NjM...")
```

не опеделяет иммено атрибут say 
версия питона 3.5.5
токен несколько раз менял
[image: вот ошибка]
уже 3 день стараюсь помогите

Comment: извените за ошибки

Comment: В ошибке сказано что "Бот" не имеет аттрубита "delete_message"

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `await bot.say()`, используйте `await ctx.send()`.